# Text formats all look the same?

Tags: wysiwyg, files

I am using the CKeditor and IMCE modules.

When in edit mode, I can see the following text formats in the dropdown menu under the body text area:

- Filtered HTML
- Full HTML
- Plain text
- PHP code

I am logged in as an admin, selecting different text formats from the dropdown menu does not change anything on the page. For example, selecting Plain text, doesn't remove the icons at the top of the text area. What am I doing wrong/missing?

Selecting the PHP code option however does change the appearence of the text area in a sense that the icons disappear.

Comment: installing Wysiwyg module consider an option for you?

Comment: The fact that your site: A) has the `PHP Filter` module enabled and B) Your role has permission to access it... is not a good sign.

Comment: Thank you @AdamBalsam
I am however the admin, and logged in as the user that first setup the site... Is that still a bad sign?

Comment: Completely unrelated to your question, but worth mentioning anyway. Yes, PHP being an option under any circumstances is bad.

Answer (score 0):

**This is expected behavior.**

The "Text Format" Select List affects the way drupal parses and displays the data **after it has been saved and is being displayed to the end user**; not the way it is saved nor the way it is displayed on the Node Edit form.

### By default:

**Given Input:**

```
<div>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <img src="foo.fpg" />
  <?php echo 'bar'; ?>
</div>
```

**"PHP Code" filter output**

```
<div>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <img src="foo.fpg" />
  bar
</div>
```

**"Full HTML" filter output**

```
<div>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <img src="foo.fpg" />
</div>
```

### "Filtered HTML" filter output

```
<h1>Title</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks again @AdamBalsam
So selecting the Plain text format should not make the wysiwyg icons at the top disapear?

Comment: Yes, I believe they should.

Comment: @kine456 I beg to differ; as example when selecting `Full HTML` to use as a linked [WYSIWYG](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) profile and leave the other formats without an editor, then, when switching on the edit page of the node between `Full HTML` and `Plain Text`, the editor will accordingly (diss)apear. So it's not just about the parsing of the content if you ask me.

Comment: It depends on what module is generating the icons in the first place. BuEditor will place icons above every textarea on the site regardless of input format. It will even put icons above plain-text textareas. I thought the most important thing to answer was the purpose of the Input Format select list. What happens to the textarea itself is secondary, not part of core, and will vary depending on configuration and modules used.

Comment: Thank you @Ambidex

I thought it wasn't correct especially since on one site selectinting different text types what I see changes but not on the other site. I am using CKeditor and imce. Any idea what settings I need to check in order to make the wysiwyg editor change between selecting different text types?

Comment: @kine456 The only thing you should do to make the editors switch on different text-formats is settings the editor profiles at `admin/config/content/wysiwyg` when you do that, they should automatically change when changing the text-format.